# Enemy object not attacking player object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating a game in Unity2D version v2022.3.17f1 and trying to write code for enemy attack. While the function of following the player when they are within the enemy's range works, the enemy does not stop and attack when it touches the player. Both objects have BoxCollider2D and RigidBody2D components. I would also like to add a function that pushes the player backward when attacked by the enemy and vice versa. I have attached screenshots of these components for both objects. Please help!

[Player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgFPo.png)
[Enemy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CILkv.png)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Player player;

    public float speed = 3f;
    public float damage = 2f;
    public float attackDistance = 1f;
    public float followDistance = 5f;

    private bool isAttacking = false;

    void Update()
    {
        Vector2 direction = player.transform.position - transform.position;
        float distance = direction.magnitude;

        if (distance < followDistance)
        {
            if (distance < attackDistance && !isAttacking)
            {
                Debug.Log("Enemy is attacking");
                StartCoroutine(Attack());
            }
            else
            {
                if (distance > attackDistance)
                {
                    MoveTowardsTarget(direction);
                }
                else
                {
                    StopMoving();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void MoveTowardsTarget(Vector2 direction)
    {
        direction.Normalize();
        transform.Translate(direction * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    void StopMoving()
    {
        Rigidbody2D rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    }

    IEnumerator Attack()
    {
        isAttacking = true;
        StopMoving(); 

        player.TakeDamage(damage);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);

        isAttacking = false;
        MoveTowardsTarget(player.transform.position - transform.position); 
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            StopMoving();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You set `rb.velocity` to zero - but you didn't base movement on physics and used raw translation instead. So `StopMoving();` likely won't do anything sensible. The only actual effect your coroutine has is the `player.TakeDamage(damage)` are you certain it didn't work? That `MoveTowardsTarget(player.transform.position - transform.position); ` is nonsense again - that's just a single frame worth of movement you are applying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all: Do not mix movement via `Transform` with physics! It will break the physics and collision detection.
- Also as already stated in the comments, since you move your object through `Transform` whatever you apply to the `Rigidbody2D` doesn't matter whatsoever.

  You rather want to move your object through the `Rigidbody2D` component.
- Now there further are three main options to go with when moving objects via the `Rigidbody2D`

  - Use forces (e.g. through [`AddForce`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html))

    Basically only accelerate/decelerate your object using certain forces but let the physics engine calculate the resulting movements taking all forces and collisions into account.
  - Use the [`velocity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-velocity.html)

    Directly assign/overrule the velocity yourself. The object will not react to any forces except you explicitly calculate and tell it so yourself. The movement will be blocked by collisions.
  - Use [`MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.html)

    Moves your object to a specific position calculated by yourself but still enables collision detection and being blocked by collisions

  In your use case you probably rather want to go with one of the latter two - again: Don't mix them!

So probably something like e.g.

```
public class EnemyController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Player player;

    public float speed = 3f;
    public float damage = 2f;
    public float attackDistance = 1f;
    public float followDistance = 5f;

    [SerilaizeField] private Rigidbody2D rb;

    private bool isAttacking = false;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!rb) rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        var direction = player.transform.position - transform.position;
        var distance = direction.magnitude;

        var follow = distance < followDistance;

        rb.velocity = !follow || isAttacking ? Vector2.zero : direction.normalized * speed;
        
        if (distance < attackDistance && !isAttacking)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Attack());
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator Attack()
    {
        if(isAttacking) yield break;

        isAttacking = true;

        player.TakeDamage(damage);

        // TODO - push this object and player apart from each other

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);

        isAttacking = false; 
    }
}
```